# Mongoose: Update does not work in nested array object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document with the array of objects and one object contains multiple objects I want to update inner object with `$set` but didn't get any luck. How can I resolve it?

This is my object:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("56fbfafdf86fa6161911d104"),
  "site": "xyz",
  "adsPerCategory": NumberInt(2),
  "sampledAt": ISODate("2016-03-30T16:12:45.138+0000"),
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "4563873",
      "content": {
        "title": "WATER DISTILLERS",
        "body": "Perfect to save money.",
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "4563s23232873",
      "content": {
        "title": "Cola water",
        "body": "Perfect for body.",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to update `body`.

for now, I have given `single object` but it can be multiple.

Here what I tried

```
models.Sample.update(
  {
    _id: samples._id
  },
  '$set': {
    'items.0.content.body': body.description
  },
  function(err, numAffected) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log('Affected....', numAffected);
  }
);
```

It's working fine if I put `0` but I want to make it dynamic.

Like `'items.index.content.body': body.description`

Comment: you mean , you want to update all the items with the same body content?

Comment: Nope, items has multiple objects and each object has different body content  
so that I used `foreach` for iterating and updating all the body with different contents

Comment: I just updated body value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this.

```
models.Sample.find({ _id: ObjectId(samples._id) })
   .forEach(function (doc) {
       doc.items.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
          items[index].content.body = body.description;
        });
   models.Sample.save(doc);
 });
```

Comment: I already tried this but didn't work, with this everything will be update except array items

Comment: can you try setting `doc.markModified('doc.items')` and see if it helps? just put it before `models.Sample.save(doc);`